# Reverse for 'profile/{{user.username}}' not found. 'profile/{{user.username}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'profile/{{user.username}}' %}">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'settings' %}">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

`<li><a href="{% url 'profile/{{user.username}}' %}">Profile</a></li>`
Here I can't use this Django format to redirect at user's profile page
but if do it like
`<li><a href='/profile/{{user.username}}'>Profile</a></li>`
I can use this way.
Why I am not able to use Django url?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
    path('likes', views.likes, name='likes'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('follow', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    path('about', views.aboutus, name='about'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('settings', views.settings, name='settings'),
    path('profile/<str:pf>', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

here is my url patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "name" you specified as first parameter, then your args. So `{% url "profile" user.username %}`

Note: `{% url "profile" pf=user.username %}` should also work